# ISO 8601 parsing validation in Carbon

Tags: php, date, php-carbon, iso8601

I am passing a date to my backend through ajax. The date is in ISO 8601 format and in UTC (E.G. 2017-07-04T23:21:37.000000Z). I am going to pass this string to create a carbon instance. Is there a way for carbon to throw an exception if the string I am passing is not ISO 8601 format? Basically I am looking for a function like

moment("2017-07-04T23:21:37.000000Z");

for momentjs or

```
parseISO("2017-07-04T23:21:37.000000Z");
```

for date-fns. The Carbon::parse method accept many accepted format so not good in my use case.

Comment: I don't think it has one, but you can always use parse to create the date, then see if `toIso8601String()` is equal to the string being passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Carbon::createFromFormat. Carbon is an extension of DateTime. I show it with DateTime, so it's reproducible for everyone.

```
$strISO8601 = "2017-07-04T23:21:37.000000Z";
$format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO";
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $strISO8601);
```

If the format is not correct the result is false.

From the Carbon Doc:

Carbon::createFromFormat() is a wrapper for the base php function DateTime::createFromFormat. The difference being again the $tz argument can be a DateTimeZone instance or a string timezone value. Also, if there are errors with the format this function will call the DateTime::getLastErrors() method and then throw a InvalidArgumentException with the errors as the message.

Comment: And if you want to throw an exception, that can be done with a simple `if($dateTime === false) throw new Exception()`.

Comment: Carbon throws an exception itself. I added an excerpt from Carbon-Doc to my answer.